# Additional fields to model with separate forms

Tags: django, forms

I have a model Customer which has some general fields like name phone etc and some fields that are more private like ssn id tax_id etc. so it is like this

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    #general fields
    #more private staff fields
```

I want to have one form to create a new customer but I want them to be in different tabs (well my employer does want that). What would be the best practice? Have different models so different forms?

```
class Customer(models.Models):
   #general fields

class PrivateFields(models.Model):
   #private fields
   customer = models.OneToOneField(Customer)
```

The above method would require the usage of two different forms to be rendered in one template. If I want one form (first method one model) would something like that stand or will it have issues:
I am using bootstrap3:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
    <li><a href="#general-info">General</a></li>
    <li><a href="#private-details">Private</a></li>
</ul>

<form class="inline">

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="general-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="text">Home</label>
                    <input type="text" id="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Small">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="private-details">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="profile">Profile</label>
                    <input type="text" id="profile" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="profile">
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit form">
    </div>
</form>
```

[bootply link](http://bootply.com/107450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any reason to have them in separate models, or even two separate forms. Tabs are just divs that are shown/hidden by some Javascript, so you can simply put the 'public' fields in one div and the 'private' ones in the other.

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="general-info">
    <div class="field">
        {{ form.generalfield1.label_tag }}
        {{ form.generalfield1 }}
        {{ form.generalfield1.errors }}
    </div>
    ... etc ...
</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="general-info">
    <div class="field">
        {{ form.privatefield1.label_tag }}
        {{ form.privatefield1 }}
        {{ form.privatefield1.errors }}
    </div>
    ... etc ...
</div>
```

If you want to do it in a more generic way, perhaps you could define a list of public/private field names in the view:

```
public_fields = ['name', 'address']
private_fields = ['trustworthy', 'bank_details']
```

and check membership as you iterate through:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="general-info">
  {% for field in form %}
    {% if field.name in public_fields %}
    <div class="field">
        {{ field.label_tag }}
        {{ field }}
        {{ field.errors }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

etc.

Comment: I see this is what I originally thought.Thank you!